# Multiple files with single fileupload issues in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have **one fileupload** that can select multiple files. But the server side only receives the last selection when I click submit. For instance, first time I select 2 images, then 3 images,totally 5 images. After submitting, server catchs only 3 last images. My idea is putting all the images into one hidden input, then server will get data from hidden input. But I don't know how to put them in hidden input.

My question is how to put data image into a hidden input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clone the actual file input. Here's an example:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(':file').change(function () {
            if (this.files.length > 0) {
                var real = $(this);
                var cloned = real.clone(true);
                real.hide();
                cloned.insertAfter(real);
                real.appendTo('form');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Files, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple", value = "", id = (string)null })

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
}
```

The idea is that the original file input is outside of the form. Then everytime the user performs a file selection we are cloning the field and inserting it into the form as a hidden file input. When the form is submitted all files will be uploaded to the server.

A further improvement of the script would obviously be to provide some visual indication to the user of the number of files that are going to be uploaded to the server.